# memory for iOS push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have a vps with a 512M memory, and I want to use it as a push notification server for my iOS app, at the time I push messages to 2,000 users(2,000 device tokens),the vps would down since using too much memories.
Now I have 30,0000 users, is there any way to push messages to all these users?
or what size of memory I should prepare for 30,000 users?

Comment: What are you running on the server to do the pushes? How many users will you typically be pushing to at once?

Comment: @Kitsune apns.py,and now I can only push to 1,500 users at once.